# Display ImagesViews with animation issue

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-animation, android-adapter

I want to display `ImageViews` in `GridView` using animation. I can display them and apply animation correctly.

But issue is that, if I apply animation on ImageView1 and then to ImageView2 (before animation on ImageView1 is ended) then animation on ImageView1 gets interrupted and ImageView1 is directly set to final state.

Note that I download image using `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 2 threads. Whenever an image is done downloading, I call `addImage(image)` method of below `ImageAdapter` which in turn adds image in `GridView` and `GridView` is refreshed to display latest set of images. And Here, while rendering, new image is displayed with animation and this animation(I guess) interrupts animation of currently animating images.

**ImageAdapter :**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Bitmap> images;
    private ArrayList<Integer> colors;
    private boolean[] alreadyLoadedIndexes;
    Animation animation;
    AnimatorSet animator;

    public void addImage(Bitmap img) {
        images.add(img);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setAnimation(Animation animation) {
        this.animator = null;
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    public void setAnimator(AnimatorSet animation) {
        this.animation = null;
        this.animator = animation;
    }

    public void resetImages() {
        images.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        alreadyLoadedIndexes = null;
        alreadyLoadedIndexes = new boolean[20];
    }

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        colors.add(Color.CYAN);
        colors.add(Color.BLUE);
        colors.add(Color.GRAY);
        colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
        colors.add(Color.MAGENTA);
        alreadyLoadedIndexes = new boolean[20];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView
                .setBackgroundColor(colors.get((int) ((Math.sqrt(position) + 2 * position) % 5)));

        // If image at index 'position' is available
        if (images.size() > position) {

            // If loading this image first time then only apply animation
            if (!alreadyLoadedIndexes[position]) {

                // If animation is specified
                if (this.animation != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
                    imageView.startAnimation(animation);

                }
                // If animator set is specified
                else if (this.animator != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                    imageView.setBackgroundColor(colors.get((int) ((Math
                            .sqrt(position) + 2 * position) % 5)));
                    animator.setTarget(imageView);
                    animator.start();
                    Log.e("", "setting image after " + animator.getDuration()
                            / 2);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(
                            new runnable(imageView, images.get(position)), 500);

                } else {
                    // Use default animation if nothing is specified.
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
                    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                            R.anim.fade_in);
                    imageView.startAnimation(animation);
                }

            } else {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
            }

            alreadyLoadedIndexes[position] = true;

        }

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        return imageView;
    }

    class runnable implements Runnable {

        ImageView image;
        Bitmap bitmap;

        public runnable(ImageView img, Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.image = img;
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("", "setting image.");
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try layout animation controlor for GridView, it will animate the views item by item with respect to time duration. check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html) ,

Comment: Please give small example code. Also I have used `GridView` not `GridLayout`. `GridLayoutAnimationController` is for `GridLayout`.

Comment: layout animation controler is applying any layout group, gridView is become a layout group, plese check this sample it will help you.   http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/wave-layout-animationexample/

Comment: in your adapter remove all the animation functionality and place in activity, and use AnimationSet not AnimatorSet, layout animation controller is take Animation Objects only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply the animation outside adapter getView method like:

```
mGridView.getChildAt(childIndexNeededToAnimate).startAnimation(animation);
```

These child views are independent and not being recycled anymore since they are already drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You have some alternative.

First you can use `Animation in your adapter` class if you don't want to change your code.
For that [check this](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/04/listview-animation-tutorial.html).

In your adapter class inside the `getView` you have to call animation like this ,

```
 Animation animation = null;
 animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_left_in);
 animation.setDuration(500);
 convertView.startAnimation(animation);
 return convertView;
```

Second you should use [GridLayoutAnimationController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html) in which A layout animation controller is used to animated a grid layout's children.

- [Sample 1](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.java.shtml)
- [Sample 2](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/wave-layout-animationexample/)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. I'm neither sure if it will help nor if I read your code right. I suppose the problem is harder than I guess.
However, you are using the same animation object for every item. Maybe you should create a new animation for each item. This could be the reason why your animation stops when you launch a new one because the new call just reuse and restarts it.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You problem is `notifyDataSetChanged();` it interrupt the animation. Try calling it when the animation is finished.

Comment: But when I have ,for example, 50 images to display and if I'll wait for each image's animation to complete before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` then it'll take around 15-20 sec to load all images.

Comment: @Akash So please explain how do you want it to behave?

Comment: I want all images to complete animation but also want to keep image loading time as less as possible. Concurrent image animations is what I seek rather than one by one.

Comment: @Akash Image is playing animation while another image just been downloaded, should it wait for the first image to finish animation or what?